# How to create clickable texts like in e.g. Instagram app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, uilabel, instagram

Below the published image in Instagram are the comments of some other users. You can click on any of them to open their profile.

[image]

How to create something like that? With label, webview, any other widget?

Comment: Yes, this is the simplest solution. Please make it an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: you have any better suggestion in simple text or can you provide source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a UIButton with type Custom and simply set a title.

You can access access and modify the label property except the text with the titleLabel property
but you must use setTitleForState to actually put text in the button
then on your button simply addTarget at selector for state userinteractiontouchupinside

```
    self.webLink = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [self.webLink setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.webLink setTitleColor:[UIColor customColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.webLink addTarget:self action:@selector(pushWeblink:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.webLink.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h);
    self.webLink.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    self.webLink.titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.webLink.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"yourFont" size:12];
```

Comment: you have any better suggestion in simple text or can you provide source code?

Comment: this is simple for button adding code? can it create example view like above image the click able text color and another unclickable text color?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `UITextView` with `editable` property off. Or you can use [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) if you want something lighter.

Comment: this is great tutorial i like this but there are some features are remaining in `OHAttributedLabel` like add actions like `button settarget method` although good example. for target method i have used this links answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058615/performing-selector-on-uilabel-generates-crash