# App crashes after adding gesture UITapGestureRecognizer to UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer

I'm fairly new to Objective C. I am trying to add a tap gesture recognizer to the UILabel. But the app crashes when trying to call the selector method. Here's what I am doing.

```
     - (instancetype)initWithCard:(Card *)obj {
//few lines of code here...
     UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.selectionHeaderLabel action:@selector(onLabelTapped:)];
                    _selectionHeaderLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                    [self.selectionHeaderLabel addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    }

    -(void) onLabelTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {
        if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
            //do some stuff
        }
    }
```

I followed this answer, but that is not helping me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9058735/4863339

**EDIT**: Here is the crash report

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel onLabelTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8c4f5252e0'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011027334b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f7d821e objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001102e2f34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
>       3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001101f8c15 ___forwarding_** + 1013
>       4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001101f8798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>       5   UIKit                               0x000000010da5f289 -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] + 57
>       6   UIKit                               0x000000010da67028 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 109
>       7   UIKit                               0x000000010da64af7 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 227
>       8   UIKit                               0x000000010da63d83 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 891
>       9   UIKit                               0x000000010da4fe56 _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1395
>       10  UIKit                               0x000000010da4f89b -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 521
>       11  UIKit                               0x000000010da4ea7e -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 286
>       12  UIKit                               0x000000010d58d7ad -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3989
>       13  UIKit                               0x000000010d53aa33 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
>       14  UIKit                               0x000000010dd2cb6d **dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
>       15  UIKit                               0x000000010dd25817 __handleEventQueue + 4879
>       16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110218311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>       17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001101fd59c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
>       18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001101fca86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
>       19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001101fc494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
>       20  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000114460a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
>       21  UIKit                               0x000000010d51cf34 UIApplicationMain + 159
>       22  CollPoll                            0x000000010bdcf8df main + 111
>       23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011267a68d start + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: show the crash report

Comment: Maybe it's becasue of "initWithTarget:self.selectionHeaderLabel"

Comment: @kb920 - so what should I do to prevent the crash?

Comment: set the target of your gesture recognizer to `self`

Comment: make sure this is `self.selectionHeaderLabel ` uilabel property of ele

Comment: write "self" our there

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are passing the target wrong. just pass self instead of self.selectionHeaderLabel.

Then, code will be like this :

```
- (instancetype)initWithCard:(Card *)obj {

   UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onLabelTapped:)];
                _selectionHeaderLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                [self.selectionHeaderLabel addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Yes; this worked :) Why is it that I have add initWithTarget as self instead of my label?

Comment: This is because the target method that needs to call is in same class.So self is the reference of that class.